# Removing iPad support from app

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded an app to the App Store a while ago, but I have to delete the iPad support for different reasons. I am not talking about removing the app from the iPad App Store, only removing the iPad support. The [Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html) states the following:

> Developers who wish to issue updates, but remove device support, have three choices:
>
> - Fix their app so that it can work on the devices they originally set out to support.
> - Target a newer version of iOS that requires a newer device.
> - Remove their app from the store, and upload the new app with a different bundle ID.

The problem is that if I remove the app from the app store and upload it again, I can not use the same app name. That is not an option.

Is there any way out of this mess?

Comment: Looks like you're stuck with option #2.  A 4th option would be remove the support and hope Apple doesn't notice. Apple will probably notice.

Comment: @BrianV It might not just be a matter of Apple noticing; their *system* will probably notice. If you've uploaded your bundle with iPad support previously and try and change that setting, I have a feeling it'll catch you out right then and there. I suppose OP would have to try to be sure, though. Also, I find it amusing that option #1 isn't really an option at all. "If you want to remove decide support, fix your app so it runs on all devices." Yeah...that's not removing device support.

Comment: @WendiKidd Yeah I know.. That was what I ended up doing anyway, had no other choice. I just love to work for free.

Comment: @BrianV: How can option #2 work? There's no "newer version of iOS" that doesn't support iPad.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't in your case if you're already target the latest version of iOS. Targeting the latest version of iOS is probably not the best thing to do when you develop an app though, unless your app requires a specific feature that is only available in that version.  Apple's policy actually makes  good sense if you think about it: you wouldn't want to upgrade your app only to find that it no longer works on your iPad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answering my own question - no, there is no other way! I ended up creating a decent looking iPad app to fix the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Apple will not allow you to remove support for iPad if you ever offered it on a given app name. Further, the app has to be well enough designed for iPad that Apple likes it enough to allow it to pass. We had an app rejected for this reason.