# Expo: Remove iPad support on non published app

Tags: react-native, expo, app-store

I'm completely new to React Native, Expo and App development in general.

I'm building a React Native app solely for iOS using Expo. I've finally managed to finish a version I'm happy with, tested with users etc. I've now been spending time adding all the required screenshots, text, info etc to App Store Connect in order to submit the app. While doing that, I learned that iPad app screenshots was mandatory, which I found weird.

I later found that I had "supportsTablet: true" in my App.json file, so it makes sense that it's expecting iPad pictures. After changing this and making a new build and submitting that, it's still a requirement.

After Google a bit I can see that it has been impossible to change this:
[Removing iPad support from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259513/removing-ipad-support-from-app)
[iOS App Submission : remove iPad support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373578/ios-app-submission-remove-ipad-support)
[iOS App Submission want to remove iPad support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376788/ios-app-submission-want-to-remove-ipad-support)

This led me down the road of trying to upload the app as a new submission. I can't get this to work though. According to this documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1623/_index.html

I should change bundle identifier and upload again. Changing this in app.json under expo.ios.bundleIdentifier doesn't work though, as I just get an error that I've already uploaded this app previously.

What are the steps I should do to reupload the app as a new submission, so that I can not support iPad?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to upload a new version, you must increase the version and the build number. You can find this if you open the project in Xcode under the General tab and the Identity section. In the same tab, you will see the Deployment Info section where you can untick the iPad. Check the picture attached.

[image]

Comment: Does this respond to the problem ???
What if we use expo EAS build services to build our application, how do we do it without XCode ?

Answer (score 7):

If you use Expo and EAS build service to build your application, to disable Ipad support you need:

1. Increase the version and the build number in app.json (expo.version and expo.ios.buildNumber.
2. Set supportsTablet to false in app.json (expo.ios.supportsTablet)